# RatingBar touch position is inaccurate

Tags: android, ratingbar

This is my RatingBar:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rbFeedback"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSubmitFeedback"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

This is my onRatingBarChangeListener:

```
float ratingscore = 5.0f;
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rating);
    rbFeedback = findViewById(R.id.rbFeedback);
    rbFeedback.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){
        @Override public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser){
            ratingscore = rating;
        }
    });
}
```

When I click anywhere between the middle of the 3rd star (2.50) and the middle of the 4th star (3.49), it selects 4/5 stars. **Why does clicking in the middle of the 3rd star give 4 stars?**

So if I click on the middle of the 3rd star, it selects 4/5 stars.

These are the results that it is giving me for each range:

```
click 0.00 to 0.49 = 1 stars
click 0.50 to 1.49 = 2 stars
click 1.50 to 2.49 = 3 stars
click 2.50 to 3.49 = 4 stars
click 3.50 to 5.00 = 5 stars
```

This seems to be default behavior and not a bug, but I don't want this behavior.

I would like this range:

```
click 0.00 to 0.99 = 1 stars
click 1.00 to 1.99 = 2 stars
click 2.00 to 2.99 = 3 stars
click 3.00 to 3.99 = 4 stars
click 4.00 to 4.99 = 5 stars
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I ran your code and it worked like you wanted it to. Changing step size to "0.5" makes it behave like you're saying it is. Also, visibility is set to "invisible". Are you sure this is the rating bar that's not working? Please check your project again carefully.

Comment: Yes, visibility is being set elsewhere when it is shown. And I have the same problem whether I use stepSize 1.0 or 0.5.

Comment: Have you tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the standard behavior and not a bug, but it is not the behavior that I want. The behavior I want is for it to accurately show how many stars the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue. I change step size from 1 to 0.1 and handle it in activity. I get the rating every time click on the rating bar. Then compare it to get the number of stars.

```
    if (ratingNumber >= 0f && ratingNumber <= 1f) {
        rating.setRating(1f);
    } else if (ratingNumber >= 1.1f && ratingNumber <= 2f) {
        rating.setRating(2f);
    } else if (ratingNumber >= 2.1f && ratingNumber <= 3f) {
        rating.setRating(3f);
    } else if (ratingNumber >= 3.1f && ratingNumber <= 4f) {
        rating.setRating(4f);
    } else if (ratingNumber >= 4.1f && ratingNumber <= 5f) {
        rating.setRating(5f);
    }
```

Hope it helps you or someone else.